# Random Disconnects on UNET

Tags: networking, server, unity-networking

Using UNET, I can't host a game for more than a few minutes unless both server and client are on the same computer. It appears that I am [not alone in this.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1177292/random-disconnections-while-using-unet.html)

Essentially, any latency problems or packet loss triggers an immediate disconnect. Rather than just getting lag, the client gets booted.

Does anyone know how this could be dealt with?

Comment: you can try changing delay value in Network Manager from 0.01 to any higher value. 0.9 worked normally for me.

Comment: Yes, this was resolved by changing the delay value in the network manager.

Comment: i will move comment to answer ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try changing delay value in Network Manager from 0.01 to any higher value. 0.9 worked normally for me.